# Could not load python310.dll while setup Python.Included for Numpy.NET

Tags: python, c#, numpy

I'm trying to use [Numpy.NET](https://github.com/SciSharp/Numpy.NET) and [Python.Included](https://github.com/henon/Python.Included) in my very first C# application. I'm developing on Ubuntu 20.4.

Here is my `Program.cs`:

```
using System
using Numpy;
using Python.Included;
using Python.Runtime;

namespace CSharpApp
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Installer.SetupPython().Wait();
            Installer.InstallWheel(typeof(np).Assembly, "numpy-1.16.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl").Wait();
            PythonEngine.Initialize();
            var npp = Py.Import("numpy");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the content of `csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Numpy" Version="3.7.1.28" />
    <PackageReference Include="Python.Included" Version="3.10.0-preview1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When I execute `dotnet run`, I'm getting the error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Delegates' threw an exception.
     ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Could not load python310.dll with flags RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL: python310.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
       at Python.Runtime.Platform.PosixLoader.Load(String dllToLoad)
       at Python.Runtime.Runtime.Delegates.GetUnmanagedDll(String libraryName)
       at Python.Runtime.Runtime.Delegates..cctor()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at Python.Runtime.Runtime.Delegates.get_Py_IsInitialized()
       at Python.Runtime.Runtime.Py_IsInitialized()
       at Python.Runtime.Runtime.<>c.<Initialize>b__26_0()
       at Python.Runtime.Runtime.TryUsingDll[T](Func`1 op)
       at Python.Runtime.Runtime.Initialize(Boolean initSigs)
       at Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.Initialize(IEnumerable`1 args, Boolean setSysArgv, Boolean initSigs)
       at Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.Initialize(Boolean setSysArgv, Boolean initSigs)
       at Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.Initialize()
       at CSharpApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/ab/c#apps/CSharpApp/Program.cs:line 20
```

It seems trying to load python310.dll (python 3.1?). My machine has python 3.7 and 3.8 installed. Is it the reason?

Comment: `python310.dll` is Python 3.*10*, not Python 3.1. You'll need to install that version since that is what the code you are running clearly expects.

Comment: @BoarGules If my understanding is correct, Python.Included packages embedded Python (python-3.7.3-embed-amd64.zip) in its .NET assembly and automatically deploys it in the user's home directory upon first execution. No need local installation. That's what it said in its github page.

Comment: All I am saying is that the DLL in the error message is part of Python 3.10. Your question looks to me more like a bug report that should be directed to the support team of the Python Included team. But you might be able to solve the problem by installing Python 3.10 and copying the DLL to the broken embedded installation.

Comment: @BoarGules I'm trying to convert python [np.fft.fft()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html) into C# version. C# NumSharp library doesn't have that function and Numpy.NET also not working with Python runtime on my machine. Do you have any suggestion on this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I had to move to Windows that can point python correctly